# Write in English using a foreign keyboard layout on iPad

Tags: ios, keyboard, internationalization, spellcheck, ipados

As a bilingual user, this is something that have frustrated me for a while now.

The OS defaults to changing the keyboard layout along with the input language. However, physical keys don’t move around just because you decide to write in a different language.

When using a physical keyboard on my iPad or iOS devices, I really would like to be able to type Norwegian, English (US) and English (UK) text without changing the keyboard layout at all.

Can it be done, or will I just have to either disable spell checking or live with key placements changing with every input language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the keyboard connected, Go to settings/general/keyboard/hardware keyboard and for English tap over at the right edge.  You will get a list of layouts to choose from.  Instead of “automatic”, select Norwegian or whatever layout you prefer.  Do the same for other languages you need to spellcheck.

Comment: Funny how I never saw the hardware keyboard option before you mentioned it.

Comment: @Roy It does disappear if the keyboard is not connected.